# Why isn't my Animate.css working?

Tags: html, css, css-animations, font-awesome

I got a piece of code from this website (github): https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/. So this gives CSS code for CSS animations, and I decided to take the SlideInDown animation.

I put this in my CSS code, except it isn't working: what I am trying to move is a icon from Font Awesome: https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/arrow-down/

Here is my HTML:

```
<p>
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-down fa-5x slideInDown"></i>
</p>
```

CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes slideInDown {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }

  to {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes slideInDown {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }

  to {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}

.slideInDown:hover {
  -webkit-animation-name: slideInDown;
  animation-name: slideInDown;
}
```

Why isn't this working? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css#usage), you just need to add the class `animated` to your element.

```
<i class="fa fa-arrow-down fa-5x slideInDown animated"></i>
```

If you aren't using the entire animate.css library, you will need the `.animated {}` properties from [the stylesheet](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/daneden/animate.css/master/animate.css) as well.

Comment: You could try adding:
`.animated.infinite {
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}`. Or post your code so I can see the glitch.